# как брать по два значения из списка python

Tags: python

предположим у меня есть список

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

мне нужно получить

```py
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать функцию `zip` и срезы.

```py
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> list(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
>>> list(map(list, zip(lst[::3], lst[1::3], lst[2::3]))) # for three
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> for current, next in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]):
...     print(current, next)
...
```

Comment: Только в вопросе не требовалось чтобы списки перекрывались.

Comment: @GrAnd Спасибо, исправил.